# Configure .NET Core to use x86 SDK

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to change my .NET Core Web Application to use the x86 version of the .NET Core SDK.

I installed the x86 version from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#preview). I can see it in *C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003131*

I updated my global.json to this:

```
{
    "projects": [ "src" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131",
        "architecture": "x86"
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

*The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003131 which is not installed or cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet. These components are required to build and run this project. Download the version of .NET Core SDK specified in global.json or update the SDK version in global.json to the version that is installed.*

I guess I need to tell my application to look in *C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet*

How do I do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe you still have x64 on the path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.

When I installed the x64 version, it created an entry in my PATH environment variable called *C:\Program Files\dotnet*. I uninstalled the x64 version and installed the x86 version. However, the un-installation of the x64 version did not remove the *C:\Program Files\dotnet* from my PATH. So, I removed it manually, and made sure that the entry that the x86 version added, *C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet*, existed.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, can you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: I ran into the opposite problem where I wanted 64-bit but had an entry in PATH for "c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\dotnet", I corrected the entry to "c:\ProgramFiles\dotnet" which is where 64-bit SDKs are installed.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort out this issue by creating a `Directory.Build.targets` file in the root of your project.

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup 
      Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' and
                 '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and
                 '$(SelfContained)' != 'true'"
                  >
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x86'">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x64'">$(ProgramW6432)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now, with both SDKs installed (x64, x86), the compiler will find the correct platform, as specified in your project build settings.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been looking to find something like this for over a day now...

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, my install didn't even add the PATH variable. Adding the 64-bit path variable and restarting visual studio worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is known, once the previous versions have been uninstalled

[The install this based on the correct **release version and target platform**](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md#missing-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Incase it will help somebody, I am going to explain the solution.
Go to control panel -> write in the search environmental variables -> edit the system environmental variables -> environmental variables -> system variables -> Path and press edit.

Once you there, move "C:\Program Files\dotnet" bellow "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet".

restart your terminal and it should work